# Call Cassandra function without selecting (with CQL)

Tags: cassandra, cql

There is a number of Cassandra built-in functions, for example `now()` or `uuid()`. Is it possible to call those functions without a `SELECT` operation, using CQL? So far I have to do

```
SELECT count(*), uuid() from table;
```

Where `table` is a table that's always empty.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no, you cannot call functions like `uuid()` and `now()` without executing a query/upsert.  But I do have a way to keep you from having to maintain an empty table.

```
SELECT uuid() FROM system.local;
```

`system.local` will:

A) always be there.

and

B) only ever contain a single row.

It's similar to what you're doing now, but again, it prevents you from having to maintain an empty table just to gen-up a UUID.

**Upsert example**

If I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE timetest (
  yearmonth TEXT,
  id UUID,
  value TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (yearmonth, id));
```

I can INSERT to it and gen a new UUID like this:

```
INSERT INTO timetest (yearmonth,id,value) 
VALUES ('201601',uuid(),'v1');
```

Comment: Ty. Can you please give an example of how to do this with an upsert?

Comment: Ty. But I can't insert and get simultaneously, right? If I wanted to use that function's result as a primary key, I can't quite do it, as I won't know what that'd be...

Comment: @PawelVeselov good point.  In that case you may want to consider generating the UUID client-side, just so you have it.